# Performance tests to a web page

Tags: performance, selenium, testing, jmeter, load

I have this project in where I want to do load tests on a web page.

I initially learned Selenium but then realized it is more for how a web page works. I also tried Jmeter, but I want to do load tests including the user's behavior, such as clicking, uploading files, retrieving files, and so on.

I tried as well with the plugin for Selenium in Jmeter but it seems to open a navigator for each thread. My test will consist of a maximum of 14000 threads, so I wanted to know if you know some tools or what do you recommend in these cases. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no free solution for this. But you can run your JMeter tests with Selenium Plugin in the cloud (running a 5000 threads with Selenium WebDriver test will cost about $10 for the AWS).
Check this [Webdriver Example in Java](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/11/webdriver-example-in-java/) for more information

Btw, you can upload files via JMeter (without Selenium), you may simulate clicks (if they do requests).